# Bringing data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a question to solve for my school project. This snippet helps me to pull some data from the products table into the page.However, I am having a problem in the urun_galeri section. I want to update the condition here as urun_resim, but I can't. I don't know how to pull the data right out of these codes because we weren't taught that in school.

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf0sa.png)

I want to get the data from the urun_resim table here. Can you help me ?

My Codes:

```html
if ($where->urun_kategori != '[]') {
  $urun_kategori = kategori_row(json_decode($where->urun_kategori)[0]);
}

if ($where->urun_galeri != '[]') {
  $urun_galeri = json_decode($where->urun_galeri);
}

if ($where->urun_varyant != '[]') {
  $stok = 0;
} else {
  $stok = $where->urun_stok;
}
if ($where->urun_varyant != '[]') {
  $urun_varyantlar  = json_decode($where->urun_varyant);
  $stok_say  = [];
  foreach ($urun_varyantlar as $vyant_id => $vyan_arrays) {
    foreach ($vyan_arrays as $vyant_ozellik_id => $vyan_ozellik_arrays) {
      if ($vyan_ozellik_arrays->vozellik_stok == "") {
        $stok_say[] = 999;
      } else {
        $stok_say[] = $vyan_ozellik_arrays->vozellik_stok;
      }
    }
  }
  $varyant_stok = array_sum($stok_say);
} else {
  $varyant_stok = 0;
}
if ($varyant_stok == 0) {
  $urun_stok = $stok;
} else {
  $urun_stok = $varyant_stok;
}
$benzer_urunler = urun_yeni($urun_kategori->kategori_id, 6);
$urun_bno = urun_bno($where->urun_bno);
```

The photo comes with the codes here

```html
<?php if ($where->urun_galeri) { ?>
            <?php if ($where->urun_galeri != '[]') { ?>
              <div class="cz-product-gallery">
                <div class="cz-preview order-sm-2">
                  <?php $i = 0;
                  foreach ($urun_galeri as $galeri) {
                    $i++; ?>
                    <div class="cz-preview-item <?php if ($i == 1) {  echo 'active'; } ?>" id="galeri_<?= $i ?>">
                      <img class="cz-image-zoom" src="<?= base_url('uploads/urunler/' . $galeri) ?>" data-zoom="<?= base_url('uploads/urunler/' . $galeri) ?>" alt="<?php echo $where->urun_ad; ?>">
                      <div class="cz-image-zoom-pane"></div>
                    </div>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="cz-thumblist order-sm-1">
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "but I can't" - why not? What does that mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase because i don't know 'Cause we've never been taught

Comment: What **exactly** don't you know? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I don't know how to pull the data right out of these database because we weren't taught that in school.

Comment: What **exactly** is missing? Querying a database through PHP is well documented in tons of tutorials, and if your school asks for homework that is hasn't taught yet, why not ask your teacher?

Comment: Of course, the teacher is already dying to give the answer right away!

Comment: Telling someone to "please be quiet" is considered very rude on this site which is mostly run by volunteers. You might not like someone's comment, but that is no cause to shut someone down in that fashion. SO is also not a tutorial site, however the official [PHP tag here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) has many links for you to explore including [PHP Essentials](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_Essentials) which covers database-related topics in chapter 21.

Comment: We're happy to help you with a specific issue if necessary,  but we're not a replacement for doing the necessary learning and making an attempt- in other words we're not a teaching service or a free code-writing provider. You can learn the basics of database access in 1000 places if the school didn't teach you (but really they _should_ have given you enough classes to prepare you for the assignment...if not, raise it with the tutor). Do some reading, then try something. If you get stuck, show your attempt and explain the problem, and that's where we can help. See also [ask] and the [tour].

Comment: However it sounds like you _might_ already have a more specific issue but aren't explaining it clearly. Remember we're not inside your head. You say ` I want to update the condition here as urun_resim`...but what do you mean? That's a bit ambiguous. Do you mean you want to set a different condition than `if ($where->urun_galeri != '[]')`? If so, what is the logic of the new condition you want to set?

Comment: Also you said `I want to get the data from the urun_resim table`...but looking at your picture, urun_resim appears to be a _column_ not a table. Terminology is important. If you describe something inaccurately, then you can expect the people you're talking to might start to get a bit confused.

Comment: Now, we don't known really what the `$where` variable is or what it contains, but I'd guess it's probably contains a row of data from your query results. So then if you want to get data from urun_resim,  surely it's just `$where->urun_resim`? After all, that's the same way you are accessing the `urun_galeri`, and all the others.